# QListView takes too long to update when given 100k items

Tags: qt

I have a problem with reading file, specific is I want to make a small dictionary. In file which I need to read has content like this:

```
a   Ph  P6
a   snsr    CA
a b c   fb  Dj
a b c - book    i+  BS
A except B gate oOPa    y
a font  kQ  BU
[....]
```

It has about 109.000 lines, and file just has size about 2MB. In my QT app, I coded like this to read and add items to QListWidget:

```
QString sWord;
QFile inFile("C:\\EV\\ev.index");

inFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly|QIODevice::Text);
QTextStream in(&inFile);
while(!in.atEnd())
{
     sWord = in.readLine();
     myListWidget->addItem(sWord); //myListWidget is a QListWidget
}
```

But it reads too long! At first I think reason is my app reads line by line, so I coded its again like this:

```
QString data;
QStringList listWord;
QFile inFile("C:\\EV\\ev.index");


inFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly|QIODevice::Text);
QTextStream in(&inFile);
data.append(in.readAll());
listWord.append(data.split('\n'));
myListWidget->addItems(listWord);
inFile.close();
```

It works faster!(about 5 seconds since app launched), still long, I want it to read faster. What I have to do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. The list widget's layout takes too long. Set your list widget's `uniformItemSizes` property to true. This avoids expensive layout operations. Another way would be to set the `layoutMode` property to `QListView::Batched`. This avoids having to expensively lay out all of the items at once.
2. Don't use a `QListWidget` if a lower overhead `QListView` would do.
3. Additions of large numbers of elements should be batched, i.e. do not insert the elements into the model one-by-one. Insert elements from each batch in an atomic operation that emits the `rowsInserted` or `columnsInserted` signal only once.
4. You must not do any file loading in the GUI thread. This is a source of bad user experience in a lot of applications and must be discouraged with a heapful of scorn. **Don't do it**.

Below is a minimal example that takes all of those into account.

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/filemodel-18548048
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QtConcurrent>

void makeLines(QBuffer &buf, int count = 1000000) {
   buf.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text);
   char line[16];
   for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
      int n = qsnprintf(line, sizeof(line), "Item %d\n", i);
      buf.write(line, n);
   }
   buf.close();
}

struct StringListSource : QObject {
   Q_SIGNAL void signal(const QStringList &);
   void operator()(const QStringList &data) { emit signal(data); }
   Q_OBJECT
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   QApplication app(argc, argv);
   QListView view;
   QStringListModel model;
   StringListSource signal;
   QObject::connect(&signal, &StringListSource::signal, &model, &QStringListModel::setStringList);
   QtConcurrent::run([&signal]{
      QBuffer file;
      signal({"Generating Data..."});
      makeLines(file);
      signal({"Loading Data..."});
      QStringList lines;
      if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
         while (!file.atEnd())
            lines.append(QString::fromLatin1(file.readLine()));
      file.close();
      signal(lines);
   });
   view.setModel(&model);
   view.setUniformItemSizes(true);
   view.show();
   return app.exec();
}
#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: You saved me! In accordance with your advice in item #1, I made a call to `ui->listView->setUniformItemSizes(true)`. I was adding ~1.5 million items to a `QListView` using a custom model derived from `QAbstractItemModel` and it was taking minutes. Setting `setUniformItemSizes` to true cut the time down to under 1 second. Thanks for this tip!

Comment: Amazing answer! Thank you. I'm designing a music library, so same concept. Printing out information on 100,000 songs read from a database file. I've been waiting about 15 minutes now for the view to load.