# Efficient way to to display log messages in UI

Tags: python, qt, qt4, pyqt, pyside

I have a message source. This constantly emits signals for log messages. These log messages should be visualized in some way in the user interface. Since there are a lot messages (up to 100 per second in peak situations) this must happen quite efficiently.

For this I had 2 approaches:

1. Using a `QTextEdit`

   - This doesn't worked well. Using `insertHtml` and positioning the curser took a long time. For this the UI began to be unreponsive
2. Using a a `QTableView` with an attached `QAbstractTableModel`

   - The data is inserted to the model. This automatically updates the view. Additionally the `dataChanged`-signal is connected to `QTableView::scrollToBottom` so that always the new messages are shown.

Unfortunately both approaches don't work efficient enough. The second one is better but scrolling down to the bottom needs a lot of ressources.

Can someone help me with a better solution to display log messages?

Comment: I think you should save your messages on a queue and with a timer you can show the messages on the UI since the last time (1 sec or less if you need)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `QTextEdit` and `QPlainTextEdit` are quite slow and unsuitable for anything but the most minor logging. The formatting operations they perform are very expensive and not designed for log use - in practice, fast logging to a text edit ends up locking up the GUI.

The `QTableView`, or even `QListView`, are very fast in comparison. Note that the model that is appended to does not emit `dataChanged` signal - because no existing data is changed, and that's the signal's meaning. The model is emitting the `rowsInserted` signal after each insertion (among other signals).

The list view needs some tweaks to behave fast, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18579171/1329652).