# Qt: How to create a scrollable, owner-drawn widget

Tags: c++, qt

I need to create a scrollable, owner-drawn widget that behaves a lot like `QPlainTextEdit` with word-wrapped text, in the sense that the height depends on the width - as the content width decreases, the content height increases.

What is the best approach to do it? I was thinking about putting my `QWidget-derived` class inside a `QScrollArea`, but `QPlainTextEdit` is derived from `QScrollArea` instead, should I go that route?

Also, I want to paint only the visible area in `paintEvent()`, it would be wasteful otherwise.

Right now I'm examining the code of `QPlainTextEdit`, but it is rather complex and not easy to read, so if anyone knows of a code example that's simpler on the web, you can give me a link, it would help a lot.

Comment: You definitely want it to be a `QScrollArea` unless you fancy your own reimplementation of scrolling. I'd seriously look at `QListView` since it pretty much does all this, and you have full control over how fancy you wish to be when rendering each paragraph of text. It performs much better than `QPlainTextEdit` (with a [caveat](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18579171/1329652)). Getting the editing functionality would be a bit trickier. A bare list view showing a `QStringListModel` is like a plain text edit for constant data :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll post the solution I came up with. It's not the best, but it mostly works.

I did not derive from `QAbstractScrollArea` in the end, instead I simply embedded my widget in a `QScrollArea` with a vertical layout, which worked well-enough.

I implemented `resizeEvent()` (I saw this from `QPlainTextEdit` implementation), and each time the width changes, I recalculate the height, and I set the widget's minimum height to that. I set the minimum height because of how the layout works.

```
void MyWidget::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *e)
{
    // If the widget's width has changed, we recalculate the new height
    // of our widget.
    if (e->size().width() == e->oldSize().width()) {
        return;
    }

    setMinimumHeight(calculateHeightFromWidth(e->size().width()));
}
```

For drawing only the visible area see [Get visible area of QPainter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22259173/get-visible-area-of-qpainter)