# Get visible area of QPainter

Tags: c++, qt, qtgui, qpainter, qevent

I have an owner-drawn `QWidget` inside a `QScrollArea`, so when painting, and I want to paint only the parts that are visible. To do so, I need to have the rectangle of the visible area of the `QPainter`.

The only candidates were `QPainter::viewport()`, `QPainter::window()`, and `QPainter::clipBoundingRect()`, so I put this code to log their output:

```
    setMinimumHeight(3000);
    setMinimumWidth(3000);
}
void MyWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    QPainter painter(this);
    qDebug() << painter.viewport() << painter.window() << painter.clipBoundingRect();
```

Then I moved the horizontal and vertical scrollbars, but the logged output was strange:

```
QRect(0,0 3000x3000) QRect(0,0 3000x3000) QRectF(-21,-21 0x0) 
QRect(0,0 3000x3000) QRect(0,0 3000x3000) QRectF(-1,-21 0x0) 
QRect(0,0 3000x3000) QRect(0,0 3000x3000) QRectF(-1,-1 0x0)
```

As, you can see, none of these functions give the actual visible area, how do I get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try this instead:

```cpp
void MyWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *paintEvent)
{
    qDebug() << paintEvent.rect();
}
```

See the [QPaintEvent::rect documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpaintevent.html#rect) for details.