# QListView with millions of items slow with keyboard

Tags: c++, qt, qlistview, qabstractitemmodel, model-view

I'm using a `QListView` with a custom model derived from `QAbstractItemModel`. I have on the order of millions of items. I have called `listView->setUniformItemSizes(true)` to prevent a bunch of layout logic from being called when I'm adding items to the model. So far, everything works as expected.

The problem is that **using the keyboard to navigate the list is slow**. If I select an item in the list, then press up/down, the selection moves fast *until* the selection needs to scroll the list. Then it becomes extremely laggy. Pressing page-up or page-down is also very laggy. The problem seems to be when an item is selected (aka the "current item") with the keyboard and the list is also scrolled up/down.

If I use the mouse, navigating the list is fast. I can use the mouse wheel, which is fast. I can drag the scroll bar up/down as fast as I want--from the top of the list to the bottom--and the list view updates wickedly fast.

Any ideas on why the combination of changing selections and scrolling the list is so slow? Is there a viable work-around?

### Update 9/9/15

In order to better illustrate the issue, I'm providing amplifying information in this update.

## Performance Issues with KEYBOARD + SCROLLING

This is mostly a performance question, although it does tie in with the user experience (UX) somewhat. Check out what happens as I use the keyboard to scroll through a `QListView`:

[image: Slow Scrolling Issue]

**Notice the slow-down near the bottom?** This is the focal point of my question. Let me explain how I am navigating the list.

**Explanation:**

1. Starting at the top, the first item in the list is selected.
2. Pressing and *holding* the down arrow key, the current item (selection) is changed to the next item.
3. Changing selection is fast for all of the items that are currently in view.
4. As soon as the list needs to bring the next item into view, the selection rate slows down significantly.

I expect that the list should be able to scroll as fast as the typematic rate of my keyboard--in other words, the time it takes to select the next item should not slow down when the list is scrolled.

## Fast Scrolling with MOUSE

Here's what it looks like when I use the mouse:

[image: Fast Mouse Navigation]

**Explanation:**

1. Using the mouse, I select the scroll bar handle.
2. Quickly dragging the scroll bar handle up and down, the list is scrolled accordingly.
3. All movements are extremely fast.
4. Note that **no selections are being made**.

This proves two main points:

1. **The model is not the problem.** As you can see, the model has no problem whatsoever performance-wise. It can deliver the elements faster than they can be displayed.
2. **Performance is degraded when selecting AND scrolling.** The "perfect storm" of selecting and scrolling (as illustrated by using the keyboard to navigate through the list) causes the slowdown. As a result, I surmise that Qt is somehow doing a lot of processing when *selections are being made during scrolling* that aren't normally performed.

## Non-Qt Implementation is FAST

I want to point out that my issue seems to be specific to Qt.

**I have already implemented this type of thing before using a different framework.** What I am trying to do is within the scope of model-view theory. I can do exactly what I am describing at blazing fast speeds using [juce::ListBoxModel](http://learn.juce.com/doc/classListBoxModel.php) with a [juce::ListBox](http://learn.juce.com/doc/classListBox.php). It's stupid fast (plus, there's no need to create a duplicate index such as a `QModelIndex` for every single item when each item already has a unique index). I get that Qt needs a `QModelIndex` for each item for its model-view architecture, and although I don't like the overhead cost, I think I get the rational and I can live with it. Either way, I don't suspect that these `QModelIndex`es are what is causing my performance slow-down.

With a JUCE implementation, I can even use the page-up & page-down keys to navigate the list, and it just blazes through the list. Using the Qt `QListView` implementation, it chugs along and is laggy, even with a release build.

A model-view implementation using the [JUCE framework](http://www.juce.com/) is extremely fast. **Why is the Qt `QListView` implementation such a dog?!**

## Motivating Example

Is it hard to imagine why you'd need so many items in a list view? Well, we've all seen this kind of thing before:

[image: Visual Studio Index]

This is the Visual Studio Help Viewer index. Now, I haven't counted all of the items--but I think we'd agree that there are a lot of them! Of course to make this list "useful," they added a filter box that narrows down what is in the list view according to an input string. There aren't any tricks here. It's all practical, real-world stuff we've all seen for decades in desktop applications.

But are there *millions* of items? I'm not sure it matters. Even if there were "only" 150k items (which is roughly accurate based on some crude measurements), it's easy to point out that you have to do something to make it useable--which is what a filter will do for you.

My specific example uses [a list of German words as a plain text file with slightly more than 1.7 million entries (including inflected forms).](http://sourceforge.net/projects/germandict/files/) This is probably only a partial (but still significant) *sample* of words from the German [text corpus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_corpus) that was used to assemble this list. For linguistic study, this is a reasonable use case.

Concerns about improving the UX (user experience) or filtering are great design goals, but they are out of the scope of this question (I'll certainly address them later in the project).

## Code

Want a code example? You got it! I'm not sure how useful it will be; it's as vanilla as it gets (about 75% boilerplate), but I suppose it will provide some context. I realize that I'm using a `QStringList` and that there is a `QStringListModel` for this, but the `QStringList` that I'm using to hold the data is a placeholder--the model will eventually be somewhat more complicated, so in the end, I need to use a custom model derived from `QAbstractItemModel`.

```
//
// wordlistmodel.h ///////////////////////////////////////
//
class WordListModel : public QAbstractItemModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    WordListModel(QObject* parent = 0);

    virtual QModelIndex index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex& parent = QModelIndex()) const;
    virtual QModelIndex parent(const QModelIndex& index) const;
    virtual int rowCount(const QModelIndex& parent = QModelIndex()) const;
    virtual int columnCount(const QModelIndex & parent = QModelIndex()) const;
    virtual QVariant data(const QModelIndex& index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const;

public slots:
    void loadWords();

signals:
    void wordAdded();

private:
    // TODO: this is a temp backing store for the data
    QStringList wordList;
};


//
// wordlistmodel.cpp ///////////////////////////////////////
//
WordListModel::WordListModel(QObject* parent) :
    QAbstractItemModel(parent)
{
    wordList.reserve(1605572 + 50); // testing purposes only!
}

void WordListModel::loadWords()
{
    // load items from file or database

    // Due to taking Kuba Ober's advice to call setUniformItemSizes(true),
    // loading is fast. I'm not using a background thread to do
    // loading because I was trying to visually benchmark loading speed.
    // Besides, I am going to use a completely different method using
    // an in-memory file or a database, so optimizing this loading by
    // putting it in a background thread would obfuscate things.
    // Loading isn't a problem or the point of my question; it takes
    // less than a second to load all 1.6 million items.

    QFile file("german.dic");
    if (!file.exists() || !file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
        QMessageBox::critical(
            0,
            QString("File error"),
            "Unable to open " + file.fileName() + ". Make sure it can be located in " +
                QDir::currentPath()
        );
    }
    else
    {
        QTextStream stream(&file);
        int numRowsBefore = wordList.size();
        int row = 0;
        while (!stream.atEnd())
        {
            // This works for testing, but it's not optimal.
            // My real solution will use a completely different
            // backing store (memory mapped file or database),
            // so I'm not going to put the gory details here.
            wordList.append(stream.readLine());    

            ++row;

            if (row % 10000 == 0)
            {
                // visual benchmark to see how fast items
                // can be loaded. Don't do this in real code;
                // this is a hack. I know.
                emit wordAdded();
                QApplication::processEvents();
            }
        }

        if (row > 0)
        {
            // update final word count
            emit wordAdded();
            QApplication::processEvents();

            // It's dumb that I need to know how many items I
            // am adding *before* calling beginInsertRows().
            // So my begin/end block is empty because I don't know
            // in advance how many items I have, and I don't want
            // to pre-process the list just to count the number
            // of items. But, this gets the job done.
            beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), numRowsBefore, numRowsBefore + row - 1);
            endInsertRows();
        }
    }
}

QModelIndex WordListModel::index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex& parent) const
{
    if (row < 0 || column < 0)
        return QModelIndex();
    else
        return createIndex(row, column);
}

QModelIndex WordListModel::parent(const QModelIndex& index) const
{
    return QModelIndex(); // this is used as the parent index
}

int WordListModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex& parent) const
{
    return wordList.size();
}

int WordListModel::columnCount(const QModelIndex& parent) const
{
    return 1; // it's a list
}

QVariant WordListModel::data(const QModelIndex& index, int role) const
{
    if (!index.isValid())
    {
        return QVariant();
    }    
    else if (role == Qt::DisplayRole)
    {
        return wordList.at(index.row());
    }
    else
    {    
        return QVariant();
    }
}


//
// mainwindow.h ///////////////////////////////////////
//    
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

public slots:
    void updateWordCount();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    WordListModel* wordListModel;
};

//
// mainwindow.cpp ///////////////////////////////////////
//
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->listView->setModel(wordListModel = new WordListModel(this));

    // this saves TONS of time during loading,
    // but selecting/scrolling performance wasn't improved
    ui->listView->setUniformItemSizes(true);

    // these didn't help selecting/scrolling performance...
    //ui->listView->setLayoutMode(QListView::Batched);
    //ui->listView->setBatchSize(100);

    connect(
        ui->pushButtonLoadWords,
        SIGNAL(clicked(bool)),
        wordListModel,
        SLOT(loadWords())
    );

    connect(
        wordListModel,
        SIGNAL(wordAdded()),
        this,
        SLOT(updateWordCount())
    );
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::updateWordCount()
{
    QString wordCount;
    wordCount.setNum(wordListModel->rowCount());
    ui->labelNumWordsLoaded->setText(wordCount);
}
```

As noted, I've already reviewed and taken Kuba Ober's advice:

[QListView takes too long to update when given 100k items](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18579171/2452084)

**My question is not a duplicate of that question!** In the other question, the OP was asking about *loading* speed, which as I've noted in my code above, is not a problem due to the call to `setUniformItemSizes(true)`.

## Summary Questions

1. Why is navigating a `QListView` (with millions of items in the model) using the keyboard so slow when the list is scrolled?
2. Why does the combination of *selecting and scrolling* items cause a slow-down?
3. Are there any implementation details that I am missing, or have I reached a performance threshold for `QListView`?

Comment: Is there any point in showing as many as a million?

Comment: does these millions of items fit into the view at once? If not you may have room for optimization. Show your work.

Comment: maybe you need to improve the performance of your model. Remember that QListView is querying to the model all the time. You could also insert a filter to reduce the number of added items. A list with millions of items is not very useful.

Comment: Consider submitting a bug report.

Comment: @UmNyobe Not all of the items fit into view. Any list that has over, say, ~100 items hardly fits on *any* screen at once. That's what the separation of model-view architecture is supposed to provide--you can have tons of items, then choose how they are displayed. I'm choosing to show them in a list view. Either way, I've updated my answer to show my work, as you requested.

Comment: @eferion the model performance is wicked fast. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: @n.m. I'm not sure it's a bug just yet. However, I might be pushing the limits of what `QListView` and `QAbstractItemModel` cand handle, which is what I'm trying to figure out. I want to drive to the root cause.

Comment: @KubaOber I'm not sure what "normal navigation" is, but filters can be used to do what I think you're talking about. Filtering the list is a different issue beyond what I'm trying to get accomplished here. In my updated example, I show a list of German words. The users will eventually be able to filter the list down to items they are interested in, but then when the filter is cleared, the currently selected item will remain selected. The idea is to allow users to view alphabetically similar words around their selection. The user experience is beyond the scope of my question.

Comment: @KubaOber I should have originally mentioned that I reviewed your post at http://stackoverflow.com/a/18579171/2452084. This was my bad, I should have referenced it. Would you be so kind as to review my updated answer? I tried to take your sage advice into account here, and my question builds off of your lessons learned. However, my question takes a deep-dive into a different performance issue, and in the spirit of how business on SO goes, I didn't want to hijack the other OP's thread. So, in light of my updated answer, would you mind unmarking this question as a duplicate, please?

Comment: Clearly if mouse scroll works and keyboard scroll doesn't, this is not a problem with the limits.

Comment: @n.m. It seems like Qt should be able to handle this, right? I just don't understand why selecting+scrolling incurs such a performance hit. Clearly the retrieval of data from the model, as well as rendering the display, are both fast operations.

Comment: For an example database front ends often limit the number of rows displayed.

Comment: I want to make sure I understand you correctly: do you still have the problem?

Comment: @KubaOber Yes, the problem still persists. Your suggestion improved loading times, but the selecting+scrolling performance is still an issue.

Comment: Basically, all this performance stuff is a long-standing bug. There's nothing wrong with the model-view architecture that's causing this. The `QListView` is simply unfinished in this respect - there's nothing inherent that would limit its performance, just the current implementation is deficient. I'd suggest you get a gerrit account, set up git, and fix it. You'll need to have Qt built from source anyway to trace into Qt and diagnose why it's slow, so fixing it is a short way away from there :)

Comment: @KubaOber Thanks for the background. I don't have a gerrit account yet, but I have built Qt from git. I recently compiled Qt 5.6 against Visual Studio 2015, so I'm sure it's possible to use the VS profiler to locate hot paths. Fixing the implementation might be beyond my reach at this point, but at least it's somewhat comforting to understand that it's a long-standing bug with `QListView` and not something that has an easy fix. If I get the bandwidth, this would be an interesting endeavor...

Comment: My oh my, what sheer absurdity did I live to see - giving visual studio as an example of implementation efficiency. Especially since QtWidgets are so mature and considered "done" as in "there is nothing left to improve". The same old story - developers too busy introducing more bugs and bloat...

Comment: Note that this problem is not reproductible under Linux (using LInux Mint at least). Here using arrows to navigate the scroll bar show constant speed time even when the view starts scrolling to show new elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1. Why is navigating a QListView (with millions of items in the model)
    using the keyboard so slow when the list is scrolled?**

Because when you navigate through your list using the keyboard, you enter the internal Qt function `QListModeViewBase::perItemScrollToValue`, see stack:

```
Qt5Widgetsd.dll!QListModeViewBase::perItemScrollToValue(int index, int scrollValue, int viewportSize, QAbstractItemView::ScrollHint hint, Qt::Orientation orientation, bool wrap, int itemExtent) Ligne 2623    C++
Qt5Widgetsd.dll!QListModeViewBase::verticalScrollToValue(int index, QAbstractItemView::ScrollHint hint, bool above, bool below, const QRect & area, const QRect & rect) Ligne 2205  C++
Qt5Widgetsd.dll!QListViewPrivate::verticalScrollToValue(const QModelIndex & index, const QRect & rect, QAbstractItemView::ScrollHint hint) Ligne 603    C++
Qt5Widgetsd.dll!QListView::scrollTo(const QModelIndex & index, QAbstractItemView::ScrollHint hint) Ligne 575    C++
Qt5Widgetsd.dll!QAbstractItemView::currentChanged(const QModelIndex & current, const QModelIndex & previous) Ligne 3574 C++
Qt5Widgetsd.dll!QListView::currentChanged(const QModelIndex & current, const QModelIndex & previous) Ligne 3234 C++
Qt5Widgetsd.dll!QAbstractItemView::qt_static_metacall(QObject * _o, QMetaObject::Call _c, int _id, void * * _a) Ligne 414   C++
Qt5Cored.dll!QMetaObject::activate(QObject * sender, int signalOffset, int local_signal_index, void * * argv) Ligne 3732    C++
Qt5Cored.dll!QMetaObject::activate(QObject * sender, const QMetaObject * m, int local_signal_index, void * * argv) Ligne 3596   C++
Qt5Cored.dll!QItemSelectionModel::currentChanged(const QModelIndex & _t1, const QModelIndex & _t2) Ligne 489    C++
Qt5Cored.dll!QItemSelectionModel::setCurrentIndex(const QModelIndex & index, QFlags<enum QItemSelectionModel::SelectionFlag> command) Ligne 1373    C++
```

And this function does:

```
itemExtent += spacing();
QVector<int> visibleFlowPositions;
visibleFlowPositions.reserve(flowPositions.count() - 1);
for (int i = 0; i < flowPositions.count() - 1; i++) { // flowPositions count is +1 larger than actual row count
    if (!isHidden(i))
        visibleFlowPositions.append(flowPositions.at(i));
}
```

Where `flowPositions` contains as many items as your `QListView`, so this basically iterates through all your items, and this will definitely take a while to process.

**2. Why does the combination of selecting and scrolling items cause a slow-down?**

Because "selecting and scrolling" makes Qt call `QListView::scrollTo` (to scroll the view to a specific item) and this is what ends up calling `QListModeViewBase::perItemScrollToValue`. When you scroll using the scroll bar, the system does not need to ask the view to scroll to a specific item.

**3. Are there any implementation details that I am missing, or have I reached a performance threshold for QListView?**

I'm afraid you are doing the things right. This is definitely a Qt bug. A bug report must be done to hope having this fixed in later releases. [I submitted a Qt bug here](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-68977).

As this code is internal (private data classes) and not conditionnal to any `QListView` setting, I see no way to fix it except by modifying and recompiling the Qt source code (but I don't know exactly how, this would require more investigation). The first function overidable in the stack is `QListView::scrollTo` but I doubt it would be easy to oevrride it without calling `QListViewPrivate::verticalScrollToValue`...

Note: The fact that this function goes through all items of the view was apparently introduced in Qt 4.8.3 when [this bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-21804) was fixed ([see changes](https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/18039/3/src/gui/itemviews/qlistview.cpp)). Basically, if you don't hide any items in your view, you could modify Qt code as below:

```
/*QVector<int> visibleFlowPositions;
visibleFlowPositions.reserve(flowPositions.count() - 1);
for (int i = 0; i < flowPositions.count() - 1; i++) { // flowPositions count is +1 larger than actual row count
    if (!isHidden(i))
        visibleFlowPositions.append(flowPositions.at(i));
}*/
QVector<int>& visibleFlowPositions = flowPositions;
```

Then you'll have to recompile Qt and I'm pretty sure this will fix the issue (not tested however). But then you'll see new problems if you one day hide some items...to support filtering for instance!

Most likely the right fix would have been to have the view maintain both `flowPositions` and `visibleFlowPositions` to avoid creating it on the fly...

Comment: This is as good of an answer as I guess I can hope for at this point, and you even submitted a bug report (thanks!), so I'll mark this as the accepted answer. It will be interesting to see if this is addressed in future versions of Qt. I can't say I understand the purpose of the "flow positions" in the code above, but I can appreciate the need to support hidden items.

Comment: @MatthewKraus: Neither I understand it. It's wierd to have the view save a container ending up with a hude size while the usage of a model is meant to avoid that....

Comment: @MatthewKraus: Note that the bug is planned to be fixed in Qt 5.11.1!

Answer (score 1):

I have made the following test:

First of all i create a class to check in the calls:

```
struct Test
{
  static void NewCall( QString function, int row )
  {
    function += QString::number( row );

    map[ function ]++;
  }

  static void Summary( )
  {
    qDebug() << "-----";
    int total = 0;
    QString data;
    for( auto pair : map )
    {
      data = pair.first + ": " + QString::number( pair.second );
      total += pair.second;
      qDebug( ) << data;
    }

    data = "total: " + QString::number( total ) + " calls";
    qDebug() << data;
    map.clear();
  }

  static std::map< QString, int > map;
};

std::map<QString,int> Test::map;
```

Then I insert a call to `NewCall` in `index`, `parent` and `data` methods of `WordListModel`. Finally i add a `QPushButton` in the dialog, the `clicked` signal is linked to a method which call to `Test::Summary`.

The steps of the test are the next:

1. Select the last showed item of the list
2. Press the *Summary* button to clear the calling list
3. With *tab* key select the list view again
4. Perform a scroll with the direction keys
5. Press *Summary* button again

The printed list shows the problem. `QListView` widget makes a big number of calls. It seems the widget is reloading all the data from the model.

I don't know if it can be improved but you can't do anything but filter the list to limit the number of items to show.

Comment: Wow. `QListView` is indeed querying the model excessively. It seems like you can't even hover your mouse over the `QListView` widget without hundreds of calls being made. I tried this test: select the first item, press the END key to go to the last item in the list, then press the *Summary* button. With ~1.6 million items, there were 3,211,774 calls made! (Loading makes 3,211,323 calls.) It knows how many items there are, it should be able to go to the first/last items quickly and only query the items that are in view, but it looks like every item is queried, just as you say.

Comment: Using your test harness, I measured the number of calls made when using the mouse to move the scroll bar (see the section "Fast Scrolling with MOUSE" in my question). It seems like mouse scrolling is fairly fast, taking "only" ~30,000 calls to do a moderate scroll through the list (top to bottom). Compared to the the "top to bottom" test (pressing END) I mentioned in my previous comment, mouse scrolling is 100x faster.

Comment: Just for reference, I performed a similar test to yours: go to the end of the list, press *Summary* to clear the stats, select the first word, press UP, then press *Summary*--there were 4,817,168 calls. This is ~1.6 million calls MORE than is made when the *entire* list is initially loaded.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is a Qt bug. I don't know if this issue can be solved optimizing Qt code but it is a serious problem if you need to show a listview with a very large number of items

Comment: Maybe `QListView` has more "features" than I need. It seems like making a custom widget to display a large number of items might be worth the effort. I figured I would make an attempt to use an out-of-the-box solution before rolling my own, but a custom widget might make sense in this case.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, I believe that you can't do much about this.
We don't have much control over widgets.

Although you can avoid that issue by using `ListView` instead.
If you try my quick example below you'll notice how fast it can be even using delegates which is costly.

Here is the example:

```
Window{
    visible: true
    width: 200
    height: 300

    property int i: 0;

    Timer {
        interval: 5
        repeat: true
        running: true
        onTriggered: {
            i += 1
            lv.positionViewAtIndex(i, ListView.Beginning)
        }
    }

    ListView {
        id:lv
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: 1605572
        delegate: Row {
            Text { text: index; width: 300; }
        }
    }
}
```

I put a `Timer` to simulate the scrolling, but of course you can turn on or off that timer depending on whether keys are pressed as well as changing i += 1 by i += -1 if <kbd>▲</kbd> is pressed instead of <kbd>▼</kbd>. You'd have to add overflow and underflow checks too.

You can also choose the scrolling speed by changing `interval` of `Timer`. Then it's just a matter of modifying the selected element's color etc. to show it's selected.

On top of which you can use `cacheBuffer` with `ListView` to cache more elements but I don't think it is necessary.

If you want to use `QListView` anyway take a look at this example: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-fetchmore-example.html
Using the fetch method allow to keep performance even with big datasets. It allows you to fill the list as you scroll.

Comment: Bro QListView has the potential to be much faster than QListWidget...